# Си: вывод данных нестандартных типов (int32_t)

Tags: c, указатели, память, процесс

Такая проблема: посредством функции `sched_getparam()` получил приоритет процесса в переменную Ps. Как известно, тип для представления значения приоритета является структурой `struct sched_param`, а в ней есть поле `sched_priority` типа `int32_t`, которое как раз таки обозначает приоритет. Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли вывести значение данного поля на экран (интуиция подсказывает, что да, т.к. значение приоритета (в ОС QNX) вроде как представляется целым числом)? Проблема в том, что я не знаю, какой спецификатор использовать при выводе с помощью функции `printf()`. Пробовал `%d` непосредственно, пробовал приводить `Sp->sched_priority` к `int`, но всегда происходит ошибка памяти. Может, есть какая-то функция для вывода этого значения... И вопрос касается не только типа `int32_t`, но и других нестандартных типов, с которыми позже я по-любому столкнусь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формально в `stdint.h` определены и типы (наподобие `uint32_t`, и соответствующие спецификаторы для их вывода (наподобие `PRIu32`) - воспользуйтесь ими.

Но! Судя по вашему

> Пробовал %d непосредственно, пробовал приводить Sp->sched_priority к int, но всегда происходит ошибка памяти.

у вас какая-то другая проблема. Приведите [кусочек кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который приводит к этой проблеме. Потому что ну не может спецификатор `%d` при выводе приводить к ошибке памяти. Где-то у вас какое-то неверное разыменование, скорее всего...

Comment: `struct sched_param* Sp;
sched_getparam(getpid(), Sp);
printf("%d\n", Sp->sched_priority);`

Comment: Ошибка: Memory fault (core dumped).

Comment: Я не знаю ваших конкретных функций, но скорее всего вы должны заранее выделить память под `struct sched_param` - ведь функция не в состоянии изменить значение `Sp` ну просто никак... Что бы ни делала `sched_getparam`, значение `Sp` так и останется мусором...

Comment: Я считал, что, когда передаём ссылку на мусорную переменную, в которую функция должна записать данные, последняя сама выделяет память. Хорошо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Да, Вы правы - всё работает. Теперь узнал немного нового. Спасибо!

Comment: Это же C, тут нет передачи по ссылке... Ну, если ответ вас устраивает - помечайте как принятый.